# error NAN with the local variable

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, local-variables

I have probleme of randomvariable because it don't loop so I add the var for it for turn it to a local variable , now the loop work but the probleme I receive NAN error when it come to the result() function what is the probleme am self learner so some basic I skip i want learn by pratical way , sorry for the newbie question

```
function randomvariable () {
var myarray = new Array;

myarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
 var randomvariable  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
result = (myarray[randomvariable]);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  randomvariable;

}

function launchfunction () {


myFunction();
randomvariable();
theresult();


}   

    function theresult() {

    f =  document.getElementById("dkhoul").value;
    r=randomvariable;
    var  x = f*1-r;
    var s = Math.abs(x);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  s;



}
```

Comment: you have a function with the same name as a variable. you could use descriptive function names other than `randomvariable`. better use a name like `getRandomValue`.

Comment: The line where you instantiated the array is missing a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is so much wrong with this code, I suggest you go back to the basics ... Also your purpose here is totally mysterious.

However hoping it helps, here's a functional, cleaned-up snippet that I believe respects the intent.

Good luck-

```js
function randomVariable () {
  var myArray = [];
  for(i=0;i<21;i++) {
    myArray.push(i);
  }
  var randomVar = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  result = myArray[randomVar];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  randomVar;
}

function getResult() {
  f = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  r = Math.random()*2;
  var x = f*(1-r);
  var s = Math.abs(x);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = s;
}

function launchFunction () {
  randomVariable();
  getResult();
}   

launchFunction();
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span><br>
<span id="result"></span>
```